# Jenkins Jelly template. How to parse and display string found between two labels

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I am building some projects using Jenkins. Before the projects are built I am echoing the git branches into the console log. I want to display those branches in the final email, but have no clue how to write the Jelly for that.

My log contains:

```
+ echo -e 'LABEL1Project1=gitbranch.1.0ENDLABEL1\n'
LABEL1Project1=gitbranch.1.0ENDLABEL1
```

How do I parse the console log and get the text found between two known labels?How can I display the branch using a jelly email template?

Thank you

Comment: If it's easier to parse for LABEL1Project1=gitbranch.1.0 on a single line I obviously can do that as well.

Comment: did you had a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Jelly.
 1. Install the [Email extension plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Emailtokens)
 2. Add 'Editable mail notification' post-build step
 3. According the `Content Token Reference` help menu, use Regex to customize the below instructions and include the token in your `Default Content`.

**Parse log instructions:**

> ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex, linesBefore, linesAfter, maxMatches, showTruncatedLines, substText, escapeHtml, matchedLineHtmlStyle}

Comment: I managed to find the code to do it and just updated my jelly template. Looked into your plugin, thanks.

Comment: <TD class="console">${line.substring(line.indexOf('LABELINLOGSTART')+15,line.indexOf('LABELINLOGEND'))}</TD>